# epmd error opening stream socket: Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, epmd

When trying to start rabbitmq server, I get the following error:

```
{error_logger,{{2014,9,26},{15,30,21}},"Protocol: ~tp: register/listen error: ~tp~n",["inet_tcp",econnrefused]}
{error_logger,{{2014,9,26},{15,30,21}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{net_kernel,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.21.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{error,badarg},[{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,320}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.10.0>]},{messages,[]},{links,[#Port<0.93>,<0.18.0>]},{dictionary,[{longnames,false}]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,987},{stack_size,27},{reductions,799}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2014,9,26},{15,30,21}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,net_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{'EXIT',nodistribution}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_kernel},{mfargs,{net_kernel,start_link,[[rabbitmqprelaunch791,shortnames]]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2014,9,26},{15,30,21}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_sup},{mfargs,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2014,9,26},{15,30,21}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4']}},{pid,<0.9.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}},[{application_master,init,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,133}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},{ancestors,[<0.8.0>]},{messages,[{'EXIT',<0.10.0>,normal}]},{links,[<0.8.0>,<0.7.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,376},{stack_size,27},{reductions,117}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2014,9,26},{15,30,21}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
```

I tried `erl -sname foo` command and it gave a similar error.

Then (as suggested here: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.networking.rabbitmq.general/23204) I tried
`epmd -debug` and it gave the following output:

```
epmd: Mon Sep 29 11:56:16 2014: epmd running - daemon = 0
epmd: Mon Sep 29 11:56:16 2014: error opening stream socket: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Tried to google for epmd error Address family not supported by protocol, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that you are using IP6 address which might be not supported by `epmd` in your Erlang version.  [This mail](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-February/072250.html) might shed some light on issue (or just force IP4 if you can).

Comment: And of course, if you will decide to compile new ErlangVM [using kerl](https://github.com/yrashk/kerl) is great option.

Comment: Thank you. I googled about IPv4 and erlang and found that there is an issue with ubuntu erlang package - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/erlang/+bug/1374109. So, I just installed the newest erlang version from https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp and now everything works.